# React en Hostinger

Tags: reactjs, aplicación-web, hosting

como están? tengo una duda, hice una aplicación en react, bien sencilla, usa un api de laravel, el tema es que hice el build de la aplicacion y quiero probarla online. Mi duda, es saber si la puedo colocar en Hostinger, en un subdominio, ya que solo es para probar. Y como debo hacer, si subir todo el proyecto o solo el build, y si es que funcionara, porque la verdad que no eh llegado a comprender eso del todo. En la web estoy buscando pero no encuentro nada claro. Alguien sabe esto?

Comment: Si te interesa en una pregunta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594500/can-i-deploy-my-reactjs-app-on-a-regular-host/44594670) que te pueda interesar

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ya me fijo si funciona lo que alli dice. Gracias @Capt.Teach

Comment: Genial!!!!! Funciono!!!!! Pone tu comentario como respuesta y la agrego como la correcta. Muchas gracias @Capt.Teach !!!

Comment: Vale manañana pongo la respuesta. Me alegra haberte ayudado

Comment: Ya tienes la respuesta, si ves que falta algo no dudes y avísame para actualizar la respuesta y así ayudar a los futuros usuarios. Si la respuesta te ha sido útil no olvides de darle un positivo :). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como explican en esta pregunta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594500/can-i-deploy-my-reactjs-app-on-a-regular-host/44594670) tienes que realizar los siguientes pasos:

Usamos [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) para empaquetar nuestra aplicación react. Siendo el resultado final el siguiente :

- Un empaquetado , que sera un archivo javascript .
- Tu `index.html` que incluirá dicho archivo al final del body.
- Tu `.css` (puedes tener uno o varios ya depende de lo que busques) incluido en la parte superior de tu index.html

Una vez tenemos estos 3 pasos simplemente coloca estos 3 archivos en tu servidor, tu aplicación estará disponible en tu `index.html`

Mención especial a otra posible forma de hacerlo usando **create-react-app** que podras encontrar en su repositorio de [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)